# Changing column precision on mysql table with 52 million rows

Tags: mysql

Some idiot (read: me) inadvertently added columns to a MySQL table with the wrong precision. Everything was fine until we started to deal with Japanese customers, and the columns are now not large enough.

The problem is that the table in question now has 52 million rows in it.

There are actually 18 columns (!) that are wrong, but only two that are in need of changing. If there is a way to do all 18 at once, ok. Otherwise just the two.

How can I go about doing this (on production) without locking the table or causing other issues? And ideally not taking 24 hours to do.

Is creating a new table, copying the data and then renaming/dropping the way to go?

1. Create new table with correct definition
2. Copy data from old to new
3. Rename old table
4. Rename new table
5. Drop old table

Which is best?

Comment: There are of course legitimate reasons for a table having 18 columns, all requiring non-integer, numeric data types - but note that this *can* be symptomatic of poor schema design.

Comment: Try to add `algorithm=inplace` to the alter statement. It will either work and only lock the table for a second or so, or fail with an error (depends on the column types).

Comment: @vatev As you can see in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html#online-ddl-column-operations) a complete lock would be required, so therefore this doesn't work.

Comment: @Strawberry the table actually has 30 columns. 18 need changing. It is a table that represents/holds invoicing information from a 3rd party site. there's nothing wrong with that at all.

Comment: @fancyPants it is 100% impossible to alter a table in MySQL without a full table lock. The only question is for how long it will be locked.

Comment: @Vatev Yes, what I wanted to point out is, that there's no concurrent DML allowed during the whole operation.

Comment: `algorithm=inplace` (when possible) doesn't lock the table during the entire operation. You can add an index which takes (for example) 10 minutes, and use the table during the time. It only works for certain oprerations - changing the digit count of a DOUBLE can be done inplace, while changing a DECIMAL can't.

Answer (score 1):

That is basically the way to go, yes. I'd recommend to use a tool for this. Have a look at pt-online-schema-change. It's part of the the [percona-toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-toolkit).

What it does is creating triggers on the table, so that new/updated data is transfered over to the temporary table. When it's done copying the data to the new (altered) table, it renames the tables.

An example usage would be like this:

```
# pt-online-schema-change --dry-run --alter "change col1 col1 decimal(10,2), change col2 col2 decimal(10,2)" --alter-foreign-keys-method=auto --max-load Threads_connected=500 --critical-load Threads_connected=1000 D=your_database_name,t=your_table_name,u=your_mysql_user,p=your_mysql_user_password
```

But please, read the manual carefully. 
This approach also doesn't work, when there are already triggers on the table (depending on the MySQL version you're using. Newer versions allow multiple triggers on the same table).

Comment: Thanks. I looked at pt-online-schema-change already, but the documentation is pretty dreadful. By the looks of it, it does all 5 of the steps I list...as doing a restore of our database can take 24 hours I'd rather not have it go wrong.

Comment: All I can say is, I'm a database admin with 6 years experience. I use it all the time and haven't had problems so far. But I would recommend of course to test it beforehand nonetheless.